# Connect android studio to azure sql database using Java

Tags: android, azure, android-studio, jdbc, azure-sql-database

```
 package com.example.workdb;

 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

 import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.StrictMode;
  import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

 import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.*;
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   public Button run;
   public TextView message;
   public TextView txtvw;
   public Connection con;
  @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    run= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    run.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)

        {


            CheckLogin checkLogin= new CheckLogin();
            checkLogin.execute("");
            Log.d("CREATION","ON CREATE WORKS");
            //  Log.d("txtvw", connection);
            //System.out.println("Yes");
            // txtvw.setText("hello");

        }

    });
  } public class CheckLogin extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
  {
    String z="";
    Boolean IsSuccess= false;
    String name1="";


    // Log.d("txtvw","step 1 done");
    protected void onPostExecute(String r){
        if (IsSuccess){
            message=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            message.setText(name1);
            Log.d("TAG", "STEP 1 DONE");

        }
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try
        {
            Connection con = connectionClass();
            if(con==null){
                z="Check interent";
                //Log.d("txtvw", z);

            }
            else
            {
                String query= "select * from Value";
                Statement stmt= con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery(query);
                if (rs.next())
                {
                    name1=rs.getString("KneeAngle");
                    Log.d("MYTAG", "name 1 works");
                    z="Query success";
                    IsSuccess=true;
                    con.close();


                }
                else{
                    z="Invalid query";
                    IsSuccess=false;
                }



            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return z;
    }
}
public Connection connectionClass(){
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Connection connection = null;
    String ConnectionURL ;

    try{
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbs.Driver");
```

ConnectionURL="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://havvasemserv3.database.windows.net:1433;DatbaseName=Newfin;user=******;password=******;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30";

```
        connection= DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL);

    } catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        Log.e("Error here 2 ",e.getMessage());

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("error here 3:",e.getMessage());

    }
    //Log.d("txtvw", connection);
    return connection;

}
```

}

I am trying to connect azure sql database to android studio. I have added all the permissions in the manifest file and I have also added a jtds module 1.3.1 in the project and implemented it in the gradle module app. My code exits with 0 errors but data is not displayed on the emulator. Expected output is the first value from my database which is "8".
Thanks.,

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the end of you current connection url after timeout=30
;ssl=request

Also make sure in your firewall settings of your azure server!/database your current device ip is allowed to access as by default all access is blocked,

To allow all devices to access server go to the firewall settings and in the insert ip section add this ip range

0,0,0,0 and 255,255,255,255